# iptables load balancing for TLS with request routing on the same connection

Tags: iptables, load-balancer, persistence

I am trying to set up iptables rules for TLS connection.

I have three internal IP in my machine and I route requests coming on public IP at port 443 to each of these internal IP in RR.

```
-A PREROUTING -d 10.51.10.104/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.51.10.137:1200
-A PREROUTING -d 10.51.10.104/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.51.10.136:1200
-A PREROUTING -d 10.51.10.104/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.51.10.135:1200
```

I have a problem and would be helpful if someone can help me solve it.

If a UE agent established TLS connection with my server, the request will route to IP01 as per iptable rules.

When this connection is still established and is in connected state, I would want all the TLS packets coming from this UE to be routed to IP01 and not to routed to any other IP per iptable rule.

How do I achieve it?